# Can I get shell access through SQL Server 2017 on Linux?

Tags: sql-server, linux, sql-server-2017

There is a [stored proc called `xp_cmdshell`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql) that is supposed to give you shell access on SQL Server, to the server. I am wondering if that works on Linux?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-release-notes calls out `xp_cmdshell` is not support on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sadly it doesn't, when I try `EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dir *.exe';` I get,

> **Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1, Server x230, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 1** SQL Server blocked access to procedure 'sys.xp_cmdshell' of component 'xp_cmdshell' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'xp_cmdshell' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'xp_cmdshell', search for 'xp_cmdshell' in SQL Server Books Online.

When I try to enable it with `sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;` I get

> Configuration option 'xp_cmdshell' changed from 0 to 1. Run the RECONFIGURE statement to install.

But, If I retry the `EXEC xp_cmdshell` command above I get,

```
Msg 16202, Level 14, State 200, Server x230, Procedure xp_cmdshell, Line 1
Keyword or statement option 'xp_cmdshell' is not supported on the 'Linux' platform.
```

They are such kill joys.

Comment: `xp_cmdshell` is turned off by default for a reason. You shouldn't use it in Windows either.

Comment: thank you @Evan Carroll, can you try out this? https://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/18726/xp_cmdshell-does-it-work-from-linux  I don't have a Linux machine so I cannot do it by myself. Thank you

Comment: or... sure `xp_cmdshell` cannot be executed on Linux machines, BUT, PowerShell can be installed don Linux machines. Maybe there is a way to have `xp_cmdshell` interpreted  by PowerShell on Linux